# building a form directly in a bookmarklet, is there a less verbose method?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I'm building a bookmarklet to submit a form directly to an API. For that reason I want to build the form in the bookmarklet. So far I've got this (it's rough):

```js
let popup = window.open("","","height=350, width=700, popup");
popup.document.open();
let html = popup.document.appendChild(document.createElement("html"));
html.appendChild(document.createElement("head"));
let body = html.appendChild(document.createElement("body"));
let form = body.appendChild(document.createElement("form"));
form.setAttribute("method", "post");
form.setAttribute("action", "");
let url_input = form.appendChild(document.createElement("input"));
let loc = location.href;
url_input.setAttribute("type", "text");
url_input.setAttribute("name", "url");
url_input.setAttribute("value", loc);
let submit_input = form.appendChild(document.createElement("input"));
submit_input.setAttribute("type", "submit");
submit_input.setAttribute("value", "add bookmark");
```

I need to add 3 or 4 more inputs (some of which are dynamic like the `url_input`) and probably some CSS. Is there a more manageable/efficient way of constructing this form?

Comment: I know this isn't really an answer to your question, but I would personally go with a browser extension instead. It will likely be a lot easier to build and maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to construct an HTML *string*, then insert that. The opened window will also already have a `<body>` you can use - no need to construct it, nor the `<head>`, nor the `<html>`.

```
const popup = window.open("","","height=350, width=700, popup");
popup.document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
<form method="post" action="">
  <input
    type="text"
    name="url" 
    value="${location.href}"
  >
  <input type="submit" value="add bookmark">
</form>
`);
```

If you want to add more inputs, it's as simple as writing more HTML markup. Same for styling, with a `<style>` tag.

For non-trivial code, you might consider [a userscript](https://www.tampermonkey.net/) to be more maintainable and more flexible than a bookmarklet.